# jQuery - move an element to another location in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I move the `DIV`s with class `collapse` to another location with jQuery? I want to move them from inside the `TD`s to right after the `TR`s.

I want to change the following:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="rozwin">
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-2"> // original setting div
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="mrkPoradaLp">2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="">
        <td class="rozwin">
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">  // original setting div
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="mrkPoradaLp">3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

to this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="">
        <td class="rozwin"></td>
        <td class="mrkPoradaLp">2</td>
    </tr>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-2"> // move to this location
    </div>

    <tr class="">
        <td class="rozwin"></td>
        <td class="mrkPoradaLp">3</td>
    </tr>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample-1">  // move to this location
    </div>
</tbody>
```

Comment: English dear.........

Comment: You realise this will produce invalid HTML structure and may cause problems? Would it not be better to wrap the `div` inside `<tr><td colspan="2">`

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
$('.collapse').each(function(){
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).parents('tr'));
});
```

[Example with jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fceabg5/)

**Edit**

Here the code from comment to preserve valid HTML:

```
$('.collapse').each(function(index){ 
    $('<tr><td id="collapse_' + index + '" colspan="2">').insertAfter($(this).parents('tr'));
    $(this).appendTo('#collapse_' + index);
});
```

[Example with jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6fceabg5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`clone('div.collapse').appendTo('tr.giveTrClass')`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and use[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the unwanted one.